# Implementing remote desktop connection project on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, remote-desktop

Does anyone have any idea on what libraries\technologies are needed in order to implement\provide the remote desktop functionality on Windows Phone 7?
I am new to this, just wanted to understand the intricacies involved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you just have to implement the [Remote Desktop Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol), and create a phone frontend for it.

You should look up how to do networking/sockets on Mango, and read up on how this protocol works. I think implementing it on Mango would be much easier and more performant, as you can use direct sockets, instead of having to use a HTTP wrapper.